Are there definitions of "deterministic" or "unambiguous" for EBNF-style grammars?
My understanding is that an EBNF-style grammar (similar to a Context-Free Grammar (CFG) but with added optionals, repetition and/or grouping) defines a language, but doesn't correspond to a particular CFG.
For example, the EBNF S -> a [b] . defines the language {"a b", "a"} and could be converted into at least two CFGs: S -> a T .  T -> b | . or S -> a b | a .. These are fundamentally different - for example, the first is LL(1) but the second isn't, although both are LR(1).
Since the concepts of determinism and ambiguity apply to CFGs rather than languages, is it possible to use these terms to describe an EBNF grammar? Are there natural ways to extend the CFG-specific definitions so they apply to EBNFs?

We say that $L$ is a deterministic context-free language if it is recognized by a deterministic PDA.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_context-free_language.
We say that $L$ is an inherently ambiguous context-free language if $L$ is context-free and there does not exist any unambiguous context-free grammar for $L$.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambiguous_grammar#Inherently_ambiguous_languages.

As far as I can see, EBNF only adds regular features to context-free grammars, so we can always replace all extended syntax with equivalent deterministic (right-regular) grammar rules and then left-factorize the resulting grammar to make the parts that use the new rules deterministic. The resulting grammar will have the same nonterminals plus a few new auxiliary ones; if it is nondeterministic or ambiguous, it will be because one or more of the original nonterminals have nondeterministic / ambiguous rules, so that can be your criterion.
This is no longer possible when non-context-free features are added, such as back-references. You will need to reason about automata extended to recognize these constructs and determine whether such automata can be deterministic or unambiguous. The definitions of determinism, such as $LL(k)$ or $LR(k)$, and of ambiguity (having multiple parse trees) will still apply. For instance, grammars with back-references will rarely be deterministic.
